# MongoDB query find, sum and count

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, nosql, aggregation-framework

My document of a collection is a block in blockchain with fields {height, gasUsed, timestamp}

I want to get the total gas used (sum of gasUsed) and total count, given a particular day.

Below is my query to get all blocks within 4 Jan 2022

```js
    db.getCollection('blocks').find({
        timestamp: {
            $gte: new Date(2022, 0, 4),
            $lt: new Date(2022, 0, 5)
        }
    }
```

How could I get the total count and sum of gasUsed as well (within 4 Jan 2022)?

Comment: Can you add an example of your collection and expected output?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it with Aggregation framework $match and $group:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "$and": [
        {
          "timestamp": {
            "$gte": new Date("2022-01-01")
          }
        },
        {
          "timestamp": {
            "$lt": new Date("2022-01-03")
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": null,
      "total_count": { "$sum": 1 },
      "total_gas":   { "$sum": "$gasUsed" }
    }
  }
])
```

[Working example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/TrAt3rx9iiA)

Comment: The answer is almost perfect except there is one excess } in the last 4th line. Unfortunately, I failed to update it. Please correct it if you can.

Comment: I learned something useful from your answer. We can use Date("YYYY-MM-DD") to specify the date in a more readable way, instead of Date(YYYY,M-1,D).

Comment: I am glad it helped you. Consider also upvoting and accepting my answer if it helped you.

Comment: Your answer will be accepted after fixing the unbalanced { } issue. Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean `{ }` issue?

Comment: Now I understand what you mean by `{ }` issue. I approved your edit suggestion. My original answer didn't have that issue, but someone edited the answer and added additional `}`.